# how to port forward local redis port to remote reids port using ssh

Tags: linux, ssh

I have a cloud host that installed redis, and now I did not want to expose 6379 port into public network because it is dangerous. Actually recently my host influence with a miner malware. what should I do to using ssh to forward my connect to remote machine so that I could only using 22 to connect to remote server serice. I have already tried this command but it seems not work:

```
ssh -C -f -N -g -L 6479:111.146.199.23:6379 root@111.146.199.23
```

what should I do to make it work? This is my local redis client connection config:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job

```
ssh -L 6379:127.0.0.1:6479 -N -f root@111.146.199.23
```